# Joining logstash with parent record

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm using logstash to analyze my web servers access.  At this time, it works pretty well. I used a configuration file that produce to me this kind of data :

```
{
  "type": "apache_access",
  "clientip": "192.243.xxx.xxx",
  "verb": "GET",
  "request": "/publications/boreal:12345?direction=rtl&language=en",
  ...
  "url_path": "/publications/boreal:12345",
  "url_params": {
    "direction": "rtl",
    "language": "end"
  },
  "object_id": "boreal:12345"
  ...
}
```

This record are stored into "logstash-2016.10.02" index (one index per day).
I also created an other index named "publications". This index contains the publication metadata.
A json record looks like this :

```
{
   "type": "publication",
   "id": "boreal:12345",
   "sm_title": "The title of the publication",
   "sm_type": "thesis",
   "sm_creator": [
     "Smith, John",
     "Dupont, Albert",
     "Reegan, Ronald"
   ],
   "sm_departement": [
     "UCL/CORE - Center for Operations Research and Econometrics",
   ],
   "sm_date": "2001",
   "ss_state": "A"
   ...
}
```

And I would like to create a query like **"give me all access for 'Smith, John' publications"**.
As all my data are not into the same index, I can't use parent-child relation (Am I right ?)
I read this on a forum but it's an old post :

```
By limiting itself to parent/child type relationships elasticsearch makes life 
easier for itself: a child is always indexed in the same shard as its parent,
so has_child doesn’t have to do awkward cross shard operations.
```

Using logstash, I can't place all data in a single index nammed logstash. By month I have more than 1M access... In 1 year, I wil have more than 15M record into 1 index... and I need to store the web access data for minimum 5 year (1M * 12 * 15 = 180M).
I don't think it's a good idea to deal with a single index containing more than 18M record (if I'm wrong, please let me know).

Is it exists a solution to my problem ? I don't find any beautifull solution.
The only I have a this time in my python script is : A first query to collect all id's about 'Smith, John' publications ; a loop on each publication to get all WebServer access for this specific publication.
So if "Smith, John" has 321 publications, I send 312 http requests to ES and the response time is not acceptable (more than 7 seconds ; not so bad when you know the number of record in ES but not acceptable for final user.)

Thanks for your help ; sorry for my english

Renaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be to use the [`elasticsearch` logstash filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html) in order to get a given publication while an access log document is being processed by Logstash.

That filter would retrieve the `sm_creator` field in the `publications` index having the same `object_id` and enrich the access log with whatever fields from the publication document you need. Thereafter, you can simply query the logstash-* index.

```
elasticsearch {
  hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
  index => publications
  query => "id:%{object_id}"
  fields => {"sm_creator" => "author"}
}
```

As a result of this, your access log document will look like this afterwards and for **"give me all access for 'Smith, John' publications"** you can simply query the `sm_creator` field in all your logstash indices

```
{
  "type": "apache_access",
  "clientip": "192.243.xxx.xxx",
  "verb": "GET",
  "request": "/publications/boreal:12345?direction=rtl&language=en",
  ...
  "url_path": "/publications/boreal:12345",
  "url_params": {
    "direction": "rtl",
    "language": "end"
  },
  "object_id": "boreal:12345",
  "author": [
    "Smith, John",
    "Dupont, Albert",
    "Reegan, Ronald"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Val ! The only 'problem' is that if publication metadata change the corresponding access logs will not change... it's probably the least bad solution.

Comment: If that case arises, you can still update all existing access logs using the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html)

Comment: However, it's unlikely that the author of one publication changes over time once the publication has been published, right?

Comment: Technically, you are right. Strangly, in my institution, publication authors can change 2 or 3 times per year .... from "Dupont, A." to "Dupont, Albert" to "Dupont, Amélie". A strange world as I say :-)

Comment: As ok, still the same physical persons, but using variations of names. Gotcha. Then update by query would do the job.